# How do I update the view from a different controller in angular.js without using directive?

Tags: angularjs

I have an angular app that has 2 sections on the page.

1 section is the sidebar which gives a synopsis.  Let's say it says:

```
Players 5 // {{ numOfPlayers }}
```

The code is an ajax call. I do not want to increment as this number could be increased by another call.  I NEED to run the ajax call after to get the array length.

```
angular.module('app').controller('nav', function($scope,$http) {

  $http.get('/players').then(function(data) {
     $scope.numOfPlayers = data.players.length;
  });
});
```

Now in a completely seperate controller that is on the main page.  A user can add a player.  How do I have it so I can update the nav controller?

```
angular.module('app').controller('mainController', function($scope,$http) {
    $http.post(.....).then(function(data) {
    //update the numOfPlayers so the nav is updated.
    });
});
```

Comment: You can use a service to share data between controllers.

Comment: maybe have a call to the method in the nav controller so that the scope variable updates, ultimately updating your view via the two way binding.

Answer (score 5):

### Use a Service

You can use a service to hold the shared data and `$watch` changes:

```js
var app = angular.module('TestApp', []);

app.service("playersService", function () {
    this.numOfPlayers = 0;
});

app.controller("navController", function ($scope, $http, playersService) {
    // Update the shared resource initial value with GET result
    // $http.get('/players').then(function(data) {
    //     playersService.numOfPlayers = response.data.length;
    // });
    playersService.numOfPlayers = 0;

    $scope.$watch(function () { return playersService.numOfPlayers; }, function (value) {
        $scope.numOfPlayers = value;
    });
});

app.controller("mainController", function ($scope, playersService) {
    $scope.addPlayer = function () {
        // POST and update the shared resource with result
        // $http.post(.....).then(function(data) {
        playersService.numOfPlayers++;
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="TestApp">
    <section ng-controller="navController">
        <h1>Nav</h1>
        Players {{ numOfPlayers  }}
    </section>
    <section ng-controller="mainController">
        <h1>Main</h1>
        <button ng-click="addPlayer()">
            Add player
        </button>
    </section>
</div>
```

---

### Use Parent Controller

You can use a parent controller (say pageController) to hold the shared data:

```js
var app = angular.module('TestApp', []);

app.controller("pageController", function ($scope) {
    $scope.numOfPlayers = null;
});

app.controller("mainController", function ($scope, $http) {
    $scope.addPlayer = function () {
        // POST and update the shared resource with result
        // $http.post(.....).then(function(data) {
        $scope.$parent.numOfPlayers++;
    };
});

app.controller("navController", function ($scope, $http) {
    // Update the shared resource initial value with GET result
    // $http.get('/players').then(function(data) {
    //     $scope.$parent.numOfPlayers = response.data.length;
    // });
    $scope.$parent.numOfPlayers = 0;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="TestApp" ng-controller="pageController">
   <section ng-controller="navController">
      <h1>Nav</h1>
      Players {{ numOfPlayers  }}
   </section>
   <section ng-controller="mainController">
      <h1>Main</h1>
      <button ng-click="addPlayer()">
         Add player
      </button>
   </section>
</div>
```

---

**Side Notes:**

In both approaches:

1. Might be better to use players array as a shared resource. In the example I tried to keep it simple.
2. Might be better to update the initial resource value from `mainController` and not the `navController`. In the example I tried to be consistent with your code.

Answer (score 5):

First of all I would suggest to use best practices and use component instead of ng-controller.

So you have 2 components:

```
angular.module('app').component('nav', {});
```

and

```
angular.module('app').component('main', {});
```

Now you can share state data between them via **services**:

```
angular.module('app').service('PlayersService', function(){
  this.players = [];
  this.getAll() = () => {};
  this.add(player) = () => {};
});
```

Only one tricky part is that you need to **watch** in all your components for **players** change:

```
angular.module('app').component('nav', {
   controller: function($scope, PlayersService){

     PlayersService.getAll();
     $scope.$watch(() => PlayersService.players.length, (playersLength) => this.numOfPlayers = playersLength)
   }

});


angular.module('app').component('main', {
     controller: function($scope, PlayersService){

     //PlayersService.add(player);
     $scope.$watch(() => PlayersService.players.length, (playersLength) => this.numOfPlayers = playersLength)
   }
});
```

So in both cases scope property **numOfPlayers** gets updated.

Answer (score 2):

Since you have two sections on one page my suggestion is to use a component or components instead of separate controllers. Example below:

```js
angular
  .module('exampleApp', [])
  .controller('ExampleController', ExampleController);

function ExampleController() {
  var vm = this;
  vm.numPlayers = 0;
}

angular
  .module('exampleApp')
  .component('playerSummary', {
    bindings: {
      numPlayers: '<'
    },
    template: `<p>{{ $ctrl.numPlayers }}</p>`
  });

angular
  .module('exampleApp')
  .component('playerAddition', {
    bindings: {
      numPlayers: '='
    },
    controller: function() {
      function addPlayer() {
        this.numPlayers++;
      }
      this.addPlayer = addPlayer;
    },
    template: `<button type="button" ng-click="$ctrl.addPlayer()">+</button>`
  });
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app='exampleApp'>

<head>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.5/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-controller="ExampleController as vm">
  <player-summary num-players="vm.numPlayers"></player-summary>
  <player-addition num-players="vm.numPlayers"></player-addition>
</body>

</html>
```

Not recommended, but you can also use $rootScope or catch and emit events.

You can also bind to a service property, example below, or directly to the service.

```js
angular
  .module('exampleApp', []);

angular
  .module('exampleApp')
  .controller('FirstController', FirstController);

function FirstController(PlayerService) {
  var vm = this;
  vm.players = PlayerService.players;
}
FirstController.$inject = ['PlayerService'];
angular
  .module('exampleApp')
  .controller('SecondController', SecondController);

function SecondController(PlayerService) {
  var vm = this;
  vm.addPlayer = function() {
    PlayerService.addPlayer();
  }
}
SecondController.$inject = ['PlayerService'];
angular
  .module('exampleApp')
  .service('PlayerService', PlayerService);

function PlayerService() {
  var PlayerService = this;
  PlayerService.players = [];

  PlayerService.addPlayer = function() {
    PlayerService.players.push({});
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app='exampleApp'>

<head>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.5/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div ng-controller="FirstController as vm">
    <p>{{vm.players.length}}</p>
  </div>
  <div ng-controller="SecondController as vm">
    <button ng-click="vm.addPlayer()">+</button>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

As Khalil Malki mentioned, you can watch a service value

As Jaqen H'ghar mentioned, you can use a parent controller.

Answer (score 1):

You can do that using `angular.factory()`

or `angular.service(); or $localStorage and or $sessionStorage`.

First to make a global call instead of calling inside a controller:

**Example:**

```
angular.factory('updateVal', function(){
    var data;
    return {
    getPlayers: function(){
     return $http.get('/players').success(function(results){
        data = results;
       return data;
     });
    },
   setPlayers: function(val){
     if(val){ 
      data = val;
      return data;         
      } 
      else {       
       return data;
      }
    }
   }  
});
```

**In your controller:**
First controller

```
angular.module('app').controller('nav', function($scope,updateVal){
 $scope.numOfPlayers = updateVal.getPlayers();

 $scope.$watch(function(){
    return updateVal.setPlayers().length > 0;
  }, function(){
    $scope.numOfPlayers = updateVal.setPlayers();
  })
})
```

Second controller:

```
angular.module('app').controller('mainController',       function($scope,$http,updateVal) {
    // this function update the players updateVal.getPlayers();
    $http.post(.....).then(function(data) {
    //update the numOfPlayers so the nav is updated.
     // after posting call this function:
      updateVal.setPlayers(data);
    });
});
```

**Using angular.service :**

This can be done :

```
angular.service('updatePlayers', function(){

var updatedPlayers;
this.setPlayers = function(args){

     updatedPlayers = args;
     } 
this.getPlayers = function(){
return updatedPlayers;
   }
 })
```

**In your First controller:**

```
angular.module('app').controller('nav', function($scope,$http,updatePlayers) {

  $http.get('/players').then(function(data) {
     updatePlayers.setPlayers(data.players.length);
     $scope.numOfPlayers = data.players.length;
  });
});
```

**In the second controller:**

```
angular.module('app').controller('mainController', function($scope,$http,updatePlayers) {
    $http.post(.....).then(function(data) {
    //update the numOfPlayers so the nav is updated.
     updatePlayers.getPlayers();
    });
});
```

**EDITED to fix typo**

Comment: In the factory example how do you update from the second controller?

Comment: Just to clarify you want to update the results in the controller 1 from inside of the controller two?

Comment: Yeah.  I want to update the view that is associated with the first controller.  But I want to ALSO be able to call the update function from the second controller, so the view in the first controller also can update.

Answer (score 1):

A better way to do this would be two have two directives:

1. a `page` directive
2. a `nav` directive

The `nav` directive would take some data as its input. The number of players in this case can be one of the inputs. Then, when you nest the `nav` directive inside the `page` directive, you can pass your data from `page` to `nav` and `nav` will get updated automatically when the values change:

**html**

```
<page></page>
```

**JavaScript**

```
app.directive('page', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    controller: function($scope, playerSvc) {
      playerSvc.getPlayers.then(function(resp) {
        $scope.players = resp.data;
      });
    },
    template: '<header> blah</header> <nav player-count="players.length"></nav> <footer></footer>'
  };
});

app.directive('nav', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: { playerCount: '=' },
    template: '<div> player count: {{playerCount}} </div>'
  };

});
```

By doing this, you can isolate your directives (components) and create clear boundaries. Each component or directive would have a small responsibility. In this case, `nav` gets some data and displays them and is also responsible for navigation. The `page` directive provides global data for different components or directives on the page. You can use the same idea and decide who will add the player to the list of players. And because the `nav` directive is hooked up to the `players.length`, it will be updated automatically once the `players` are updated.

Answer (score 1):

maybe have a call to the method in the nav controller so that the scope variable updates, ultimately updating your view via the two way binding

```
angular.module('app').controller('nav', function($scope,$http) {
 $rootScope.$on("CallMethodNavController", function(){
       $scope.navMethod();
    });
$scope.CallMethodNavController=function(){
$http.get('/players').then(function(data) {
 $scope.numOfPlayers = data.players.length;
}    
});
});
```

then in the second controller you call this method once a  player is added like so:

```
        $rootScope.$emit("CallMethodNavController", {});
```

Answer (score 1):

No need to create watches or events for this.

Use a service to get, store, update and share the array of players across the app.

Instead of creating a **primitive** variable that is the length ... store reference to the array in controller and in the view do `{{players.length}}` and let angular view watchers take care of updates.

```
angular.module('app').factory('playersService', function($http){
     // now have an array to share across app
     // and reference to addPlayer function
     var factory ={players:[], addPlayer: addPlayer };
     // load the players and add them to array
     $http.get('/players').then(function(response) {
         Array.prototype.push.apply(factory.players, response.data);
     });


     function addPlayer(player){
        return $http.post(url, player).then(function(resp){
           // add new player to shared array
           factor.push(resp.data);
        }
     }

    return factory;
});
```

Nav Controller

```
angular.module('app').controller('nav', function($scope,playersService) {
     $scope.players = playersService.players; // store full array reference
});
```

Nav View

```html
 Number Players: {{players.length}} <!-- angular will automatically watch and update -->
```

Other controller

```js
angular.module('app').controller('mainController', function($scope,playersService) {

    $scope.newPlayer={};// bind to ng-model's in form
    $scope.saveNewPlayer = function(){
       playersService.addPlayer($scope.newPlayer).then(function(){
           alert('Number of players in nav will already be updted');
           // clear form
           $scope.newPlayer={};
       })
    });

});
```

Answer (score 1):

use $emit and $on 
From main cintroller
     $rootScope.$broadcast('update','status'){  $http.post(.....).then(function(data) {
    //update the numOfPlayers so the nav is updated.
    });}

```
and in your nav controller use
$scope.$on('eventName', function (event, args) { $http.get('/players').then(function(data) {
 $scope.numOfPlayers = data.players.length;});});
```

$broadcast goes from parent to child so any change in parent controller will be reflected in child controller